# m2e connector quick installation for debug

Tags: m2e, connector

How do I debug an m2e connector plugin I developed? Right click -> debug As Eclipse application doesn't seem to work. Also tried to install to host. I followed the example of the antlr m2e connector with "org.eclipse.m2e.core.projectConfigurators" extension point. But m2e Maven builder doesn't seem to see the custom extension point when I do debug or run As eclipse application. What is the recommended way to debug a live m2e connector?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I too would like to debug an m2e connector and don't even know where to start.